# Error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float[0]' to binary 'operator*'

Tags: c++, graphics, syntax-error, runtime-error

So I have this code for graphics pipeline, but I am getting errors for some reason.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UpperBD 3
#define Xe 200
#define Ye  200
#define Ze  200
#define Rho  sqrt(sq(Xe) + sq(Ye) + sq(Ze))
#define PI 3.1415926
#define D_focal 20

typedef struct {
    float X[] = {};
    float Y[] = {};
    float Z[] = {};
} pworld;

typedef struct {
    float X[] = {};
    float Y[] = {};
    float Z[] = {};
} pviewer;

typedef struct{
    float X[] = {};
    float Y[] = {};
} pperspective;

void mydisplay()
{
    float p1x = 0.0f, p1y = 1.0f;    //the window coordinates (-1.0, 1.0)
    float p2x = 0.0f, p2y = -1.0f;
    float p3x = 1.0f, p3y = 0.0f;
    float p4x = -1.0f, p4y = 0.0f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    /* Line starts */
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(p1x, p1y);
    glVertex2f(p2x, p2y);

    glVertex2f(p3x, p3y);
    glVertex2f(p4x, p4y);
    glEnd();

    /* Line Ends */

    // #define Pheta = PI/4.0;
    // #define Phi =
    /* World to viewer */
    pworld world[3];
    pviewer viewer[3];
    pperspective perspective[3];

    float sPheta = Ye / sqrt(sq(Xe) + sq(Ye));
    float cPheta = Xe / sqrt(sq(Xe) + sq(Ye));
    float sPhi = sqrt(sq(Xe) + sq(Ye)) / Rho;
    float cPhi = Ze / Rho;

    for(int i = 0; i <= UpperBD; i++)
    {
        viewer[i].X = -sPheta * world[i].X; + cPheta * world[i].y;
        viewer[i].Y = -cPheta * cPhi * world[i].X
            - cPhi * sPheta * world[i].Y
            + sPhi * world[i].Z;
        viewer[i].Z = -sPhi * cPheta * world[i].X
            - sPhi * cPheta * world[i].Y
            -cPheta * world[i].Z + Rho;
        perspective[i].X = (D_focal / viewer[i].Z) * viewer[i].X;
        perspective[i].Y = (D_focal / viewer[i].Z) * viewer[i].Y;
        cout << perspective[i].X << endl;
        cout << perspective[i].Y << endl;
    }

    glFlush();
    usleep(50);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("William");
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The error occurs at `viewer[i].X = -sPheta * world[i].X; + cPheta * world[i].y;` and for the lines below it in the `for` loop. I am not sure what's going on.  I'm trying to multiply a `float` by a `float[]`, but it's not working.

Comment: Recommend adding the error message or a description of the behaviour you are seeing. Unrelated: see if you can replace those `defines` with `constexpr` variables. It really sucks when some token gets unexpectedly text-substituted.

Comment: On the statement `viewer[i].X = -sPheta * world[i].X; + cPheta * world[i].y; viewer[i].Y`, you have an erroneous `;` after `world[i].X`

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    float X[] = {};
    float Y[] = {};
    float Z[] = {};
    } pworld;
```

It's structure with 3 zero elements(empty) C arrays. `-sPheta * world[i].X;` is multiplying float(number) with empty arrays - what do you want to achieve? I guess you don't need these [].

However, I thought that zero elements C arrays are forbidden, but it compiles fine.

Comment: No, this is not valid C. The code is not written in C either.

Comment: This is invalid in C++, too